# How to access an array sent from jquery ajax post in laravel 5?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

In my jquery ajax request

```
$('#form').on('submit', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajaxpage",
                data:{
                    selected_data: JSON.stringify(selected_data),
                    },
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function( data ) {

                    console.log(data);

                }
            });

        });
```

In my controller method im trying to access the array which i have sent from ajax by looping like this

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

class AjaxController extends Controller
{

    public function postData(Request $request)
    {
        foreach ($request['selected_data'] as $data => $value)
        {
           $user->roles()->attach(role->id, ['pivot_colmumn' => $value]);
        }
    }
}
```

I think this is not a proper way. For single variable i use `$request['var_name']` and it works but for array it gives `500 internal server error.` So do i access the array values ?

Answer (score 3):

You should decode your json that sent from ajax request in your controller!

```
$select_data = json_decode($request->get('select_data'));
foreach($select_data as $key => $value){}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can fix by add token for ajax setup:

In addition to checking for the CSRF token as a POST parameter, the VerifyCsrfToken middleware will also check for the X-CSRF-TOKEN request header. You could, for example, store the token in a HTML meta tag:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then, once you have created the meta tag, you can instruct a library like jQuery to automatically add the token to all request headers. This provides simple, convenient CSRF protection for your AJAX based applications:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf

Comment: I have done all that. only problem is that i dont know how to access array in laravel

Answer (score 0):

I was actually using `JSON.stringify(selected_data)` in `jquery ajax post` request which actually converts it into a string.

So i need to use `json_decode()` to get an array then i can simply loop through it as usual.

Answer (score 0):

For access to data that send from ajax request and convert it to array, you can do something like this in your controller :

```
foreach(json_decode($request->selected_data) as $data)
{
    dd($data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did your mean `$request->var_name` and `$request->all()` ?

Laravel request returns collection

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the request object as an array when the request object is an object. Instead of using [ ] use ->.